# .replace() not working correctly

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a string that i would like to convert.

the string is image and the content is: `Gone in 60 seconds`
What i need is the following: `Gone_in_60_seconds`
But when i try: `image = image.replace(" ","_");`
the result is: `Gone_in 60 seconds`
so only the first space gets replaced.
How would i convert all the spaces to underscores?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
image = image.replace(/ /g, "_");
```

Comment: Works perfectly, care to explain what you just did? I'm eager to learn :)

Comment: the 'g' means 'global' and replaces all found instances, not just the first one, which is what the replace() method with no regex arg does. I think everyone who needs to use replace() makes this mistake at least once.